# CSS Styling for Artificial Text Input from DIV to mimic HTML input

Tags: html, css

I have a normal html `input` and an artificial one built from a div. I want them to look and behave identically.
I can achieve every aspect through CSS except for one:
The vertical centred text.
The normal HTML input centers text vertically, no matter how high the input is. You can achieve this by setting a line-height but this is not required for an native input.
So what magic is behind this?

Comment: Let's see your code so we can better assess what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, activating 'Show user agent shadow DOM' in Chrome reveals how they do it.
This is the inner HTML structure they use:

```
<div id="text-field-container" pseudo="-webkit-textfield-decoration-container">
  <div id="editing-view-port">
    <div id="inner-editor">10</div>
    </div>
  <div pseudo="-webkit-inner-spin-button" id="spin">
  </div>
</div>
```

And this flex box magic centers the input text vertically:

```
input::-webkit-textfield-decoration-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-only;
    content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your div a `table-cell` display property.

```css
.v-center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 120px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-center">This text is vertically centered</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps table-cell is what you are looking for:

//html

```
<div class="test" contenteditable></div>
```

//css

```
.test { 
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle 
}
```